Are the 11 Standard Model vertices derivable from the lagrangian alone?
The fundamental particle interactions are often graphically enumerated as so.
Is it possible to show that all these interactions, and/or no others, follow directly from the standard model lagrangian? Or does one need to employ other definitions, axioms, or initial parameters of the standard model to fully derive this shortlist?

Look at the terms in the Lagrangian involving the product of three or four fields.

I don’t think that enumeration includes vertices involving ghosts.

Feynman vertices follow from a given lagrangian. What does your text say?
